# Formatting issues with tinymce and extra linefeeds

Tags: php, tinymce

I am having trouble with Tiny mcd, in that what I type is not what is entered into my database and then displayed. I seem to get a number of extra characters (Â) and the extra line breaks.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

I type:

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

But I get:
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.Â The quick brown fox jumped
over the
lazy dog.Â The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.Â The quick brown 
fox jumped
over the lazy dog.Â The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.Â The quick 
brown
fox jumped over the lazy dog.Â The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy 
dog.Â

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.Â The quick brown fox jumped 
over the
lazy dog.Â

Â

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.Â

Comment: looks like you will have to check the character encodeing on your contents way to the DB and back

Answer (score 0):

add this on the html view part right after your opening head tag

```
meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

with the opening < and closing /> braces